# Add custom javascript section upon build in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue CLI and would like to add custom javascript section to the default template upon release. I don't necessarily want this section injected during debugging.

Example:(I'd like to add the below when running npm run build, but not present when running npm run serve)

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
if (window.location.protocol != "https:") {
  window.location.protocol = "https:";
  window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: @NikitaK thank you for the valid suggestion, Is there a way to modify the template for different environments, e.g. (production or local). Say I want to add an html element depending upon the targeted environment?

Comment: I've posted another suggestion below.

Answer (score 3):

Add it to your **main.js**

```
//...

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  if (window.location.protocol != "https:") {
    window.location.protocol = "https:";
    window.location.reload();
  }
}

// ...
// new Vue({})
```

Comment: Yes, for the scenario, (Redirecting to https if http when in production environment)

Answer (score 0):

Put it in your index.html ...
Only the div app is rewrite by vue (by default)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can read environment variable only in runtime. If you want to change your `index.html` file depending on environment *before* runtime, there is some ugly workaround:

The idea is to "swap" `index.html` file by another `index.html` from another source (directory). Every `index.html` consists of required html and javascript you want. To "swap" files you should use some `build.sh` file with instructions or `build.js` if you prefer NodeJS. After that your `npm run build` will look like: `"build": "node build.js"`.

Here is an example of `build.js` in my very old project (it's not optimal, very ugly, but did work):

```js
const mv = require("mv");
const spawn = require("cross-spawn");

console.log("Preparing environment for build...");

mv("public", "_public", err => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});

mv("build", "public", err => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});

console.log("Building...");

const build = spawn.sync("npm", ["run", "prod"]);

console.log(`stderr: ${build.stderr.toString()}`);
console.log(`stdout: ${build.stdout.toString()}`);

console.log("Reverting environment back to development...");

mv("public", "build", err => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  mv("_public", "public", reject);
  resolve();
}).then(() => {
  console.log("Done!");
});
```

Comment: Don't ask what that Promise doing there. I don't remember. :)